# Delphi go to bookmark when using Brief editor

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, brief-bookmarks

I am using Delphi XE5 (Brief editor emulation) and can't for the life of me figure out how to goto a bookmark after it's been set.  Alt+{n} where n is the bookmark number correctly sets and clears (toggles) a bookmark.  But how do you go to a bookmark once it's been set when using the Brief editor emulation.  The documentation does not address this, though it gives common shortcuts when using Brief.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move to a book mark with

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> <n>

where you need to hold down the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key while you press the <kbd>J</kbd> key, but then release <kbd>ALT</kbd> to press the bookmark number.

FWIW, I have no idea what Brief even is, but a web search led me here: http://www.dbase.com/help/Developer_Guide/IDH_KB_BRIEFKEYS.htm

Comment: That did it - thanks.  Brief is an old text editor that really rocked and was very popular in its day.  Borland bought it, integrated it into their IDEs as an optional editor. I was one of those old-timers that used it standalone but having spent most of recent days in Visual Studio, and using those keymappings, I've forgotten some of the old shortcuts in Brief.